# Is there short formula in MS Excel for multi countif combination?

Tags: excel-formula

I have database consists of equipment failure records that occured in all of our operational locations. Each location also divided to several systems.
The database is as per the below:

[image]

The summary of event quantity per month is shown in the table below (1st column), that I get from that database using countifs formula.

[image]

But if I need to fill the next columns with same formula for all columns, due to variations of combinations the formula become too long, for example: if(location<>"all",countifs(....)), if(and(location<>"all",system<>"all"),countifs(....)), etc.

Some combinations is shown in the last 5 columns, but there are still more combinations can be use.
Is there any solution to fill all the empty cells without using that too long formula?

Comment: `COUNTIFS` allows for multiple conditions. Refer each condition (e.g. System) to the according cell in your table.

Comment: @Ike, agree.. But due to so many combinations from those 4 criteria, the formula become very long: 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 24 combinations of countifs in one formula.

Comment: What Ike says. Also it might be calculating faster if you switch to something like `=LET(comb,FILTER(Range,(condition1)*(condition2),""),IF(comb="",0,ROWS(comb)))`. In that

Comment: Thanks P.b, I just still not aware of LET and FILTER formulas in MS excel.

Comment: I see the problem: the condition is different depending on "all" or a fixed value ...

Comment: if you use [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for your data it is easier to work with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 365 you can try a formula like this:

```
=LET(condition, TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,"",C$12:C$14,""),
          selectDataByCondition, MAP(data[Location],data[System],data[Equipment],data[Date],
               LAMBDA(l,s,e,d, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(condition,TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,"",l,s,e,""))) * AND(d>=$A16,d<=$B16))),
          filterData, FILTER(data,selectDataByCondition),
IFERROR(ROWS(filterData),0))
```

[image]

I am using a table for the data (called data).

The "heart" of the solution is the MAP-formula to identify the valid rows.

Plus the use of `*` instead of `all`.
Reason: within then `SEARCH`- function `*` is recognized as wildcard - and by that any value will be valid.

Maybe it helps to just copy that part  and see what happens if you change the values in the conditions section.

[image]

This result - extended by the date then is used to filter the rows of the table.

Count of rows of the filtered set is then what you are looking for.